# What's the javascript event of window rotate or toggle different device?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I was browsing to a webste with Chrome, I turned on the Inspect ( Ctrl + Shift + I ) and then I was trying to trace what javascript chart library it's using.

But I find out when I click the "Toggle Device Tollar" and switch to the mobile mode (vice versa) or press rorate when on mobile mode .

The website knows **those behaviors and reload whole page**. Not just responsive CSS but actually re-request the whole page such as the behavior of presssing F5 on the web page.

I was trying to find the javascript event  to know how it detect these behaviors(toggle on device and rorate) and do reload, but I couldn't find it via break point in the Chrome dugger.

Any ideas how this website makes it?

before pressing "toggle device toolbar"
[image]

after pressing "toggle device toolbar"
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    alert("the orientation of the device is now " + screen.orientation.angle);
});
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange).

Answer (score 2):

The orientationchange  event is fired when the orientation of the device has changed.
This link may be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange

```
// Note that "orientationchange" and screen.orientation are unpre fixed in the following
// code although this API is still vendor-prefixed browsers implementing it.

    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        alert("the orientation of the device is now " + screen.orientation.angle);
    });
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20485671)

Comment: Thanks @eisbehr for your valuable suggestion. I will include essential parts of the answer now onward.